# Additional config for php -S (url rewrite)

Tags: php, url-rewriting, slim

I'm using `php -S <app>:<port>` to run a local development server.

I am planning on using the Slim routing package but for this to work I require url rewrite since it redirects everything to the index.php file.

Any idea if this is possible or other solutions?

Comment: PHP's development server already does that. Like it says in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php): _"If a URI request does not specify a file, then either index.php or index.html in the given directory are returned. If neither file exists, the lookup for index.php and index.html will be continued in the parent directory and so on until one is found or the document root has been reached."_